# Iteratively Transform a data value

Tags: javascript

This is an extremely beginner question, but i have a value that i want to transform multiple times, each time taking the output from the previous result as input.

Lets say i want to iterate through an array of characters `[a,6,b,4]` and append each of them the word `brownbear`. The final output that i would want is `brownbeara6b4`. Also, I'm not looking for a solution that just dumps the context of the array and concatenates it to the word. I need something that can iteratively transform data, no matter what the use case is.

To maybe provide another example, i want to run a function x amount of times on some value. Each time I want to take the output of the function and use it as input for the next time the function is ran.

How would i solve this using JS?

Comment: Hi Hysii. Your post is unclear (at least to me) and therefore i can't give you an answer. When you say "iteratively transform data, no matter what the use case is" what you mean? what kind of transformation? what you want to do exactly? do you have any other example? Your current example is just a concatenation of the word `brownbear` with the array of characters joined

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Hi -- myabe a bad example. I added *hopefully* a better description of what i am trying to do

Comment: `yourarray.join('')` would create a string, with nothing as separator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a recursive function that runs X times. In that case, this can be helpful.

Basically what I'm doing here is to call the same function with the transformed data of each iteration over and over until i reach X amount of times.

```js
var my_array = ["a", "1", "b", "2"]
var times = 2

function iterative_function(data, times_to_be_run = 1){
  if(times_to_be_run > 0){
    var transformed_data = data.map(a=> a + " hello")
    return iterative_function(transformed_data, times_to_be_run - 1)
  }else{
    return data
  }
}

console.log(
  iterative_function(my_array, times)
)
```